# Sizing up Microservices using bonded context from DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, bounded-contexts

Ive heard allot about sizing up Microservices using bounded context from DDD. Any ideas what this actually means?

thanks
goaths

Comment: You must read the DDD book to understand what a BC is. It is like a subdomain, but materialized in code. Read https://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a guess, that you're heard a reference on the talk of Eric Evans on GOTO 2015 about strategic design and microservices, so you may want to watch this capture at first:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvef9R3k-M

This topic also was covered by him in a further talk:

https://www.infoq.com/presentations/ddd-microservices-2016

Comment: Thanks for the reply links are extremely helpful.. found this book too https://www.amazon.co.uk/Domain-Driven-Design-Distilled-Vaughn-Vernon/dp/0134434420/ref=s9_simh_gw_g14_i4_r?_encoding=UTF8&fpl=fresh&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=QV5N5B2Y0DC6TDB63X2Y&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=16f14aeb-bd11-4e9e-8c26-9ca0139074ee&pf_rd_i=desktop